# ¿Donde se guardan los atributos privados de una super clase?

Tags: java

según el siguiente código:

```
public class Ex1{
   protected int a;
   private int b;

   public Ex1(int a, int b){
     this.a=a;
     this.b=b;
   }
}

public class Ex2 extends Ex1{

   public Ex2(){
      super(4,2); //ejemplo
   }
}

public class Tester{
   public static void main (String [] args){
      Ex1 test= new Ex2();
   }
}
```

Al momento de la creacion del objeto referenciado por la variable test. qué es lo que ocurre con el atributo de instancia privado "b" de la clase Ex1? Tengo entendido que el objeto será creado de tipo Ex2, y dentro de su estado interno estarán sus atributos privados (si hubiesen) y los que hereda. Pero no estoy seguro dónde se guardaría el valor de "b". Lo hice en el compilador hace un rato, y sí se guarda, porque si creo un metodo getB en Ex1, puedo obtener su valor.

Comment: `si creo un método getB en Ex1, puedo obtener su valor`. Eso no es prueba, ya que al recompilar "creas" una clase "nueva". Bien podría ser que el compilador simplemente ignore `b` (que no se usa en ninguna parte) en el primer ejemplo, y al añadir el método `getB` pase a asignarle una posición de memoria (igual el JLS especifica hasta que punto la optimización es legal). La otra opción es analizar el bytecode generado para la clase en cada caso.

Comment: Puedes dar un poco mas de detalles de lo que quieres decir con "donde se guardaria el valor de b"?

Comment: Tengo entendido que cuando un objeto es creado, los valores de sus variables inicializadas en el constructor son guardadas en el estado interno del mismo objeto. Eso es lo que dibujaría al menos en un diagrama de objetos, la creación del mismo con sus valores dentro. Pero yo en ningún momento cree un objeto de tipo Ex1, solo lo cree de tipo Ex2. La variable solo es de tipo Ex1... Entonces, no sé por qué se guarda el valor de "b".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En primer lugar echemos un vistazo a la [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html), concretamente en el apartado **Private members in a Superclass**:

> Una subclase **no hereda los miembros privados de su clase padre**. Sin embargo, si la clase padre tiene métodos `public` o `protected` para acceder a sus atributos privados, estos se pueden usar en la clase hija.

(Traducido y resaltado por mi)

Esta frase es bastante esclarecedora: La clase hija **no contiene los atributos de la clase padre**. De hecho, los métodos para acceder a ellos ni siquiera son suyos, tiene que usar los que le proporciona la clase padre. Considera el ejemplo:

```
public class Ex1 {
    private int numero = 1;

    public int getNumero() {
        return numero;
    }
}

public class Ex2 extends Ex1 { }  // podemos llamar a getNumero

public class Ex3 extends Ex1{
    @Override                     // ahora getNumero pertenece a Ex3
    public int getNumero() {
        return numero;            // error! Hay que usar super.getNumero()
    }
}
```

Piensa en ello como si la clase padre tuviera sus atributos privados por separado, y si la hija quiere acceder a ellos, tiene que *pedírselo utilizando los métodos que la clase padre tiene a disposición*.

De forma interna, en el momento de instanciación, Java asigna memoria para todas las variables de instancia de la clase instanciada y todas las superiores, y los métodos que acceden a esas variables son limitados de acuerdo a las reglas de acceso.